# AWS Push Notifications service for web applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification

I have a web application and I want to send Push Notifications using AWS. I don't understand which AWS service I could use to send push notifications to web applications. It looks like AWS SNS service couldn't do that. But I can't find any examples. Tell me please what service to use?

Comment: SNS can point at a https url and send to it.  Also there is this https://developer.amazon.com/device-messaging and this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-mobile.html

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can use SNS to send http requests to Web Applications Endpoints;

2 - You can use AWS IoT to send notifications over WebSockets if you're looking for a "real time" front-end updates.

This my help you to get started with AWS IoT: http://gettechtalent.com/blog/tutorial-real-time-frontend-updates-with-react-serverless-and-websockets-on-aws-iot.html

SNS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html

Comment: I'm not looking for real time update and I'm not looking for sending http requests. I'm looking for push notifications

Comment: You mean your web application sending "Mobile Push Notifications"?

Comment: I was looking for "real time" notification so this is great.

Comment: This question is about push notifications not real time. Push notifications can be received by devices even when the website is not open in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to checking out the mobile push notifications feature of SNS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Web Push Notifications from SNS but there is more to it then just publishing a message. You need to configure VAPID keys, request user permission and save subscription on server-side.

You can read detailed guide here: [How to Send Web Push Notifications for Free with AWS and without Firebase](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-send-web-push-notifications-for-free-with-aws-and-without-firebase-19d02eadf1f7)